# TableView Viewcell Tapped action

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

How do I make use of the Tapped action in the ViewCell to navigate to other page?

Xmal codes

```
<TableView Intent="Settings" HasUnevenRows="true" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" BackgroundColor="White" >
            <TableRoot>
                <TableSection>
                    <ViewCell Height="100" Tapped="OnProfileClicked">
                         <ViewCell.View>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5,2,5,2" BackgroundColor="White" >

                                <Image x:Name="ImgProfile" HeightRequest="100"/>
                                <Label x:Name="btnName" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="Black" FontSize="20"/>
                                <Label Text=">  " FontSize="15" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Center"/>

                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell.View>

                    </ViewCell>

                </TableSection>
            </TableRoot>
            </TableView>
```

CS File

```
    public void onProfileTapped()
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new Clubs());
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so there are a couple things that are wrong with your code.

1.) You wrote `Tapped=OnProfileClicked` but the method you actually made is called `onProfileTapped()`, this is a mismatch

2.) The parameters for your item tapped event are wrong, most Xamarin events contain a sender and eventArgs.

Here's how you can fix your code to make it work:

```
void OnProfileClicked (object sender, System.EventArgs e) { //your code}
```

Also, tip, when you push a page using Navigation. You might want mark the method as async and await the action to make sure it's a smooth transition.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've changed my codes adding the async and await action however, it does prompt this error message "Method OnProfileClicked does not have the correct signature".

Comment: I think the args type I gave is wrong. Try void OnProfileClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e). I edited the solution, give that a go.